# Why My application keep giving OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, android

I am making a Web Focused crawling

and I am using String array to keep all the link

is there anyway to avoid this error

Thx

Comment: we really need to see the code that is starting this intent I think

Comment: Post your code and the Logcat messages. BTW, i was wondering, your previous log messages were unrelated to the Title.

Answer (score 0):

from the log, i can't see the out of memory error:

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from
>   outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   flag. Is this really what you want

it maybe the call ac error,plz check your code.

if use the string array to save link, in jvm, the string save to the const pool in the memory, it has a max size, if your string number is too much, maybe throws the OOM.

so, if this situation happen, suggestion to think about save some to local disk and don't save all in the memory.

Comment: If you are launching an activity from a Service, Receiver, etc. you must add that flag to your intent.  It is a common "mistake" to forget.  Since you didn't provide any code or stack trace or the length of your string, that is most-likely what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NewClass.class);
i.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
MyActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

Your title is unrelated to the exception you got.